# React js not able to create an app ... cmd hangs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

- react@16.13.1
- react-dom@16.13.1
- react-scripts@3.4.1
- cra-template@1.0.3
  added 1624 packages from 750 contributors and audited 1628 packages in 176.99s

57 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

**hangs the cmd here**

Comment: Did you try `npx create-react-app <appname>` command

Comment: It is also not working. Same problem with this also.

Comment: Try `npm audit fix` and  then try to create the react app

Comment: @PulsaraSandeepa that's not going to help. I'd suggest trying to update `node` and/or `npm` - it sounds like it's an issue with installing packages.

Comment: I have done that... solved